# Can I code Java in xcode 11.1, mac os Catalina?

Tags: java, xcode

How can I do it?
But I think intellij idea is a better solution.
I've seen some older answers but the app changed a bit since version 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

you can open any script you want like java, in Xcode an edit and run them there. like an IDE. I have used that by my selve while working with python, but now I moved to visual code on Mac which is good if you want to have a lot of different languages, or convert the script to iOS and android using Xamarin.